# i am using a Cpanel UAPI but whenever i use this api it returns me an error that unable to find get_lists_total_disk_usage in email category

Tags: php, api, cpanel, cpanel-uapi

$cpanel = new CPANEL(); //login details

// Return the total disk usage for the mailing lists of a cPanel account.

$variable = $cpanel->uapi(

'Email', 'get_lists_total_disk_usage'

);
print_r($variable);

Comment: Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

this was the error in Cpanel api and i reported to them and they fix that issue now it works fine